# How to avoid unselection when selecting a single row in PrimeFaces datatable?

Tags: primefaces, datatable, mouseevent

Using the list `people`=["Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3"] as example, and an empty list called `selectedPeople`, the following steps must be done:

1) Select one row. Result: "Person 2" added to `selectedPeople`.

List `selectedPeople`=["Person 2"]

2) Select another row. Result: "Person 3" added to `selectedPeople`.

List `selectedPeople`=["Person 2", "Person 3"]

3) Select only one of these rows. Result: "Person 2" removed from `selectedPeople`.

List `selectedPeople`=["Person 3"]

---

**Issue**: the default behavior of PrimeFaces' `dataTable` is to unselect other selected rows if I single-click one of them. It's not the best thing to tell users to hold Ctrl or Shift keys to select many records in a table.

---

What I've done until now: http://pastebin.com/qHvnZPiY

---

Comment: Why not use checkbox selection on the datatable then?

Comment: That's better, since no "workaround" is needed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid unselection, simply use attribute `rowSelectMode="add"` (but if you want it to be unselected, you need to use ctrl+click)

The solution we used in the end is to put `rowSelectMode="checkbox"` so the row is selected only when I click the first column `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />`

Then used the listeners for events `toggleSelect`, `rowSelectCheckbox` and `rowUnselectCheckbox`.

Source: [www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf)